# Manipulating data for network analysis

Tags: python, pandas, network-analysis

I am trying to manipulate my dataframe before I conduct network analysis using networkx.

Here is an sample of data i got:
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B06Kz.png)

I am trying to use the `title` and `cast` columns and trun them to something like this:
[ideal format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpAnI.png)

The ideal result is to have one column for each individual actor and the movie/show that he/she is in. If the actor has more than 1 show/movie, I want to have different rows for that actor as well.
Could someone please advise me on how to make it happen? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

So to use pandas you first import into the dataframe. Lets call it "f".

```
import pandas
f = pandas.read_csv('path/to/csv')
```

after that you can access individual columns by doing:

```
f['title']
```

similar to a dictionary. if you want both in the same dataframe, pass in a list of columns like so:

```
f[['title', 'cast']]
```

that is as much as I can provide without knowing the extent of the project.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry i did not clarify earlier. If you see the original format, there are multiple actors listed in the cast column. I am trying to have a column for each individual actor and the movie/show that he/she is in. If the actor has more than 1 show/movie, I want to have different rows for that actor as well.  pls let me know if that make sense!